# After upgrading flutter unable to build app ould not open settings generic class cache for settings file

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After ive upgrade my flutter version from 2.5.x to 2.10.3 I am unable to build my app.

Error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings remapped class cache for 3gvp67rxesfd2nfkbvtuzjg3o (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\6.3\scripts-remapped\settings_8xyk3a2se7ntfxhbq76drbyq8\3gvp67rxesfd2nfkbvtuzjg3o\settingsdeec0faa97453e2ce860d75e6bf1604b).
> Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\dev\projects\project\app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\6.3\scripts\3gvp67rxesfd2nfkbvtuzjg3o\settings\settingsdeec0faa97453e2ce860d75e6bf1604b).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Event after downgrading back to original version the same error is shown.
Ive tried deleting the gradle cache but it has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the Android Studio Cache and restarting? (File -> Invalidate Caches)

Comment: @barbecu ive got it to work now by using a random combination of deleting gradle cache, clearing android studio cache and flutter clean.